# Webpack angular2 incompatible module types

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack

I am using webpack as a packaging tool for an angular2 w/ typesript project with the following typescript compiler options:

```
// Project tsconfig.js compiler options
"compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "sourceMap": true
}
```

I am having trouble integrating the primeNG widget library. Whenever I import a component, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

I susspect the issue comes from the different module type (system) primeNG uses. Here are the compiler options:

```
// PrimeNG tsconfig.json compiler options
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "declaration": true
}
```

Is this really the cause of the problem?
Is there a way to address this with webpack?

Comment: PrimeNG is distributed using System, so for webpack I think we need to change the module to commonjs, since System.js can also consume common.js it should work. We'll work on this. If you use system.js as the loader for the project, it should work though now. There is a primeng-quickstart sample at primefaces github repository. We'll look into creating a webpack sample. There is also a related discussion at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4278

Comment: So there is no possibility to use primeNG with webpack atm? Shell I create a github issue? It would be quite useful for me if I can get expect a solution with a given release...

Comment: Please create a github issue and we'll work on it.

Comment: PrimeNG 0.6 uses commonjs  now.

Comment: There is a PrimeNG+WebPack sample here. https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart-webpack